# Как в Django организовать учёт товаров на складе?

Tags: python, django

Подскажите как в Django логичнее реализовать поступление и учёт товаров на складе?

Т.е. есть номенклатура (tovar_id, name), есть склад (может быть несколько, sklad_id, name).

Как нужно реализовывать документы поступления/отгрузки/списания?

Например, поступление 2 товаров "радио" и "игрушка" в 1 документе поступления (пусть будет 30 и 40 штук).

Я предположил, что нужно создать модели для документа и модели для транзакций по каждому товару. И связать их. Но мне кажется, что всё не так делается.

Comment: Можно сделать три доп таблицы: Тип_документа(id, name), Документ(id, doc_type_id, и дополнительные поля) и Документ_Товар (id, doc_id, tovar_id, quantity). 

и делаешь выборку select tovar_id, quentity from Документ_Товар where doc_id == (требуемый документ).  Итогом таблица товаров и их количества по нужному документу, при необходимости можно приджойнить таблицы для получения дополнительных значений